# Google Charts - don't show points when value is zero

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts to show some timeseries data like that shown below. Typically the data has a high proportion of zero values so you get lots of points sitting along the x-axis. I think this makes the chart look cluttered and I'd like to not show points where y=0.

Any ideas / pointers much appreciated.

Thanks,

ct

[image: Busy chart with data points where y=0]

Comment: I tried setting zero values to null in the JSON but that didn't work (see my comment below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want it to have all the points between the real values you can completely remove the values from your data. Keep the first 0 point right after the value and 0 point right before you have values again.

This:

```
[1000, 12],
[1001, 16],
[1002, 0],
[1003, 0],
[1004, 0],
[1005, 0],
[1006, 4],
[1007, 2],
[1008, 0],
[1009, 14]
```

Becomes:

```
[1000, 12],
[1001, 16],
[1002, 0],
[1005, 0],
[1006, 4],
[1007, 2],
[1008, 0],
[1009, 14]
```

This should only show a zero point at 1002 and one at 1005 and a line with no points between them.

Comment: Thanks Zoramite. This looks like the only thing that will work.

Answer (score 7):

The best option is to use null instead of 0 (there will be missing points). 
And then you can use option interpolateNulls which will join the values.

Answer (score 5):

Set your data to `null` instead of `0`.  However in the example chart you have shown if the first value is say `5` and the 2nd to 20th are `0` set the 2nd and 20th to `0` and the 3rd to 19th to `null`. This will display the chart correctly.

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work Fred. Setting the value to null results in a chart that looks like [this](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/d7122e04-9a6d-42d1-a8a5-e70ca82cbe01/ec0899b40c1aa6fd9781b25947fd542e/res/f5199b39-c501-438e-8772-8a11cf0a2b00/skitch.png?resizeSmall&width=832).

What I'm hoping to achieve is [this](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/ff28c593-eaf0-48f1-8a63-dd63da0134aa/f085ff78c05695a19d7964e817bdf901).

Comment: Sorry ct, I must have misread the question. You want to keep the line but not the points on the baseline? I may be wrong but I don't think that is possible. May just keep an eye on this question though!

Comment: Yep, I want to keep the line but not the points sitting on the x-axis. Looks like it's not possible though. Thanks for the suggestion though.