# Google Chart: how to join points in line Chart

Tags: google-visualization

Basically, I woul like the opposite case of this topic:
[Google Charts - don't show points when value is zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192622/google-charts-dont-show-points-when-value-is-zero)

How can I display points in 0 Values, and then joining them all together? 
Because in day 1, I have its point alone

[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/2j0cexh.png]

Comment: What do you mean with '...then joining them all together'? To show them on chart together with other points?

Comment: Yep. I meant joining day 1 with day 2, 3, 4, etc (which have a value of 0). 
But finally, I got it. It was because the values of the empty days (2 to 7 and 13 to 15) had a null value instead of 0.0 value. Finally the result is like the image

http://i61.tinypic.com/20a3upf.png